# How to print JavaScript code in my view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, string, view

I need to supply my users with js code, so I have text area:

```
  <%=  text_area_tag 'body',  "//<script>...</script>"%>
```

I can't make it working. I know how to do it with variables from controllers :

```
      @payKey = @xml["payKey"].to_s()
      "#{@payKey}"
```

**EDIT. FUll text to print:**

```
    <script>var _p_g={id:@website.id};</script>
   <script src="..."></script>
```

and print it in view, but gave me error:

```
   E:/myapp/myapp_prev/myapp/app/controllers/websites_controller.rb:12: unknown regexp option - j
   E:/myapp/myapp_prev/myapp/app/controllers/websites_controller.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
   <></script>"
                                               ^
```

So what would be better way to solve this trouble ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're putting double quotes inside of other quotes, causing a syntax error.

Try this:

```
 <%=  text_area_tag 'body',  '<script src="//cdn.printitgreen.com/js/embedded.js"></script>'%>
```

Comment: can you help me with this ? I need to print variable value : `'<script>var _p_g={id:#{@website.id}};></script>'` this only print #{@website.id}, but I need its value.

Comment: I need to use double quotes ?

Comment: Ok, you can escape double quotes using the `escape_javascript` helper:  `"<script>var _p_g={id:#{escape_javascript(@website.id)}};></script>"`

Comment: Try this: `"<script>var _p_g={id:@website.id};</script><script src=\"...\"></script>"` putting a backslash infront of the extra double quotes instead of escaping the id.

Comment: It doesn't give error, but also doesn't print website.id value.

Comment: my mistake:`"<script>var _p_g={id:#{@website.id}};</script><script src=\"...\"></script>"`

Comment: Thanks.It working ! Can I make it prints in two seprate lines ? Insert <br/> tag between two scripts ?

Comment: You can add `\n` to put a new line in: "<script>var _p_g={id:#{@website.id}};</script>\n<script src=\"...\"></script>"